# How can I extend lodash function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

It's possible extend underscore/lodash by creating mixins, but what if I would like to have a function that does something similar to existing lodash function. For example let's say I would like to add a function that compares two objects by looking into a certain property key. Function would take two objects and a property key name. Sounds easy, right?
Now imagine I would like to overload existing `_.isEqual` instead of creating brand new mixin with a different name. And in that function it would first check if first two arguments are objects and third argument is a string, and if not, then it would call original `_.isEqual` function.

I know this is not really a good idea, but I was wondering if it's doable.
I tried creating a mixin with a name `_.isEqual` that looks like this:

```
function isEqual(value, other, customizer, thisArg) {
    console.log('my own isEqual');

    return _.isEqual.apply(thisArg || this, arguments);
}
```

Apparently this didn't work, because it recursively keeps calling itself. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: `var oldIsEqual=_.isEqual.bind(_)`, then you can call oldIsEqual() if needed.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you!